# MySQL select from two tables and combine results?

Tags: mysql

I have a question about MySQL: I want to list results from a table but gather additional information about these results from another table by a foreign key.
My table YTPrograms has a foreign key called Author which corresponds to the Id of a second table called YTUsers from which I want to add the username to my result from the YTPrograms query. I'm not sure how to do this without having to query (the users table) for each result.

Comment: Have a look at joins.

Comment: marked this as too broad -- the core of the question is "how do I use relational databases", and there's tons of books written on that topic. You will need to go through some literature to really know what you're doing.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I'm aware that this is a pretty general question and I understand that you are annoyed by this. But in fact I only use this for a very small project and I don't have the time and resources to dive into SQL literature. If you don't want to answer my question, would you at least give me a tip on how find a good result on google for this specific question ? I searched for how to use JOIN but unfortunately there is a plethora of ways how to use joins and I did not find an answer to my simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.something, u.username FROM YTPrograms p, YTUsers u WHERE p.Author = u.Id
```

Comment: Would I access the results via $row["u.Name"] ?

Comment: No. Don't use the table alias - only `$row["Name"]`.

Comment: What if tables have columns with the same name ?

Comment: You can give them an alias - `SELECT a.column as first_col, b.column as second_col ...` and then call it by `$row['first_col']` or `$row['second_col']`.